# php file write permission denied on aws ec2

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

i tried write file on aws ec2 via php.

use nginx and php-fpm.

nginx www.conf

```
$ vi /etc/php-fpm-7.0.d/www.conf 

; Start a new pool named 'www'.
; the variable $pool can we used in any directive and will be replaced by the
; pool name ('www' here)
[www]

; Per pool prefix
; It only applies on the following directives:
; - 'access.log'
; - 'slowlog'
; - 'listen' (unixsocket)
; - 'chroot'
; - 'chdir'
; - 'php_values'
; - 'php_admin_values'
; When not set, the global prefix (or @php_fpm_prefix@) applies instead.
; Note: This directive can also be relative to the global prefix.
; Default Value: none
;prefix = /path/to/pools/$pool

; Unix user/group of processes
; Note: The user is mandatory. If the group is not set, the default user's group
;       will be used.
; RPM: apache Choosed to be able to access some dir as httpd
user = apache
; RPM: Keep a group allowed to write in log dir.
group = apache
```

document root is...

```
$ ll
total 56
drwxrwxr-x 20 apache apache 4096 Jun 12 06:34 ...
... 
...
```

my sources and results is...

i tried

```
$fileName = 'test.txt';
$contents = 'hello ';
$currentPath = dirname(__FILE__);

$fgc = file_get_contents($currentPath.'/'.$fileName);
file_put_contents($contents, $fgc);
```

result

> Warning: file_get_contents(/xxx/test.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /xxx/test.php on line xx

tried

```
$fp = fopen($currentPath.'/'.$fileName, "w");
fwrite($fp, $contents);
fclose($fp);
```

result

> Warning: fopen(/xxx/test.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /xxx/test.php on line xx

Comment: looks like you need to fix the file\directory permissions

Comment: nginx will (I think) run as `www-data` user so those files need to be readable and writable by that user and/or group.

Comment: The error messages seems quite clear. In the first case, you're trying to open a file that doesn't exist and in the second case, you don't have the correct file/folder permissions to write.

Comment: what is correct permissions for aws ec2(ami) ?

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, check if folder is writable, if not,

```
if ( ! is_writable($currentPath.'/'.$fileName)){

    echo 'Not writable!!!';
}
```

Then, go to `ec2 via terminal`, you need access, and use command

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/YOUR-PROJECT-FOLDER
```

Comment: how so you know the os?

Comment: i typed

$ sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /xxx/


result

chown: invalid user: ‘www-data:www-data’

Comment: please try - sudo chown -R www-data /xxx/ , seems to be www-data group does not exist, only user www-data does exist.

Comment: code result shows 'not writeable' and chown shows invalid user 'www-data'

Comment: Please try  - sudo chown -R www-data /var/www/html/YOUR-PROJECT-FOLDER

Comment: Kind of old but reviving this thread. Year is 2023. Basically, when running the command: "groups" on my EC2 instance, this is what I see: "ec2-user adm wheel systemd-journal". When trying to add www-data or www-data:www-data as suggested here, it says "invalid user" (meaning, it does not recognize it). Could use advise if any of you managed to solve it lately.